# Any way of adding member variable for specific template value?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this math vector struct:

```cpp
template <size_t _Size, typename _NumType>
struct Vector {
    _NumType elements[_Size];

    //... Other stuff ...
};
```

And I want to add variables depending on how many elements the vector has.
Something like this:

```cpp
_NumType& x = elements[0]; // Only if _Size >= 1
_NumType& y = elements[1]; // Only if _Size >= 2
_NumType& z = elements[2]; // Only if _Size >= 3
```

Making a base class/struct and then extending would be a solution but due to other code I can't do that (it would only make more problems).

Another solution I found is doing something I believe is called partial template specialization:

```cpp
template <typename _NumType>
struct Vector<2U, _NumType> {
    _NumType& x = elements[0];
    _NumType& y = elements[1];

    //... Other stuff ...
};
```

The problem with this solution is that I would have to copy "other stuff" for each specialization which is something I'd rather avoid ("other stuff" is around 70 lines of code).

In case there is no solution I can elaborate on the problem with extending a base class but I hope it won't be necessary.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Well, there's 2 options right there, 1, throw an exception when it exceeds bounds (which is what the at() methods do in the STL), or you can add an operator overload that takes a template argument that's size_t and static_asserts size, though then size would have to be compiletime

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Size`, `_Numtype`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @melpomene I said what is my problem, what solutions I considered and why none of them is something I want.

Comment: You didn't explain why you're rejecting all solutions ("*it would only make more problems*" is essentially content-free).

Comment: @Bapo I think throwing exception wouldn't solve my problem. I don't want to throw exception when vector of different size is created. I just want the references to not be there. For the other option, I don't really understand it. What operator do you mean?

Comment: @melpomene For the first solution I said I can elaborate but would rather find other solution if possible. For the second one I said it isn't ideal because I would have to copy long code many times.

Comment: I see we're already right in the middle of a frustrating X/Y discussion. GLHF

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok, I will change it.

Comment: @melpomene Look, if you want me to elaborate on the first solution, I can. If you think the second solution is good enough, fine. I asked because I wanted to know if there is a better solution I don't know about.

Comment: Where do you expect those variables to be used?

Comment: Careful with going down this path. Here is a very small example. http://cpp.sh/3rb2b

Comment: I would like to point out that a program that uses identifiers like `_Size` is *ill-formed, no diagnostic is required*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

partial template specialization can do the job, and to avoid code duplication you have to split the class, something like

```
template <size_t Size, typename T>
struct VectorData {
    T elements[Size];
};

template <typename T>
struct VectorData<2, T> {
    T elements[2];
    T& x = elements[0];
    T& y = elements[1];
};

template <typename T>
struct VectorData<3, T> {
    T elements[3];
    T& x = elements[0];
    T& y = elements[1];
    T& z = elements[2];
};

template <size_t Size, typename T>
struct Vector : VectorData<Size, T> {
    //... Other stuff ...
};
```

If you change reference to function, you might use SFINAE and since C++20, you might even discard some methods:

```
template <size_t Size, typename T>
struct Vector : VectorData<Size, T> {
    T elements[Size];

    T& x() requires (size == 2 || size == 3) { return elements[0]; }
    T& y() requires (size == 2 || size == 3) { return elements[0]; }
    T& z() requires (size == 3) { return elements[0]; }
    //... Other stuff ...
};
```

Comment: isn't `requires` part of contracts? (Which was removed from c++20, hopefully for 23)

Comment: In the first solution I had to add "using VectorData<Size, NumType>::elements;" into the Vector struct (not really sure why).

Comment: (directed at OP @MTNS) By the way, this solution is possible, works, and sounds like the solution you need, but really, this will become a mess to manage if you want more than, let's say, 3 dimensions. You're going to sort of defeat the purpose of a template by essentially having 100 different versions of your code. You might want to look into a better solution in the long run.

Comment: @JVApen No, they are part of Concepts.

Comment: @MTNS: `VectorData<Size, NumType>::elements` is dependant name, and so to use it in generic code, you have to use `this->` or `VectorData<Size, NumType>::` or bring it via `using`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you want this, however, if you don't need it to be members, you can do something like this: (C++17)

```
auto getCoordinates()
 {
      if constexpr (TSize == 1)
           return std::tuple<TNumType&>(elements[0]);
       else if constexpr (TSize == 2)
           return std::tuple<TNumType&, TNumType &>(elements[0], elements[1]);
       else if constexpr (TSize == 3)
           return std::tuple<TNumType&, TNumType &, TNumType&>(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2]);
}
```

With usage:

```
 auto [x, y, z] = v.getCoordinates(); // Assuming 3
```

Comment: You could just as easily do that with the array itself (`auto [x, y, z] = v.elements;`)

Comment: `auto &[x]` most likely. I wasn't sure if that was possible or not. That would indeed be even better!

Answer (score 2):

In the case you don't have a compiler capable of supporting constraints, or choose not to use them, an effect similar (albeit clunkier) to the [second part of Jarod42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57342590/5386374) can be achieved with the use of `static_assert`.

```
template<size_t Size_, typename NumType_>
struct Vector {
    NumType_ elements[Size_];

    // ...

    NumType_& x() {
        static_assert(Size_ > 0, "Must contain a minimum of 1 element for x.");
        return elements[0];
    }

    NumType_& y() {
        static_assert(Size_ > 1, "Must contain a minimum of 2 elements for y.");
        return elements[1];
    }

    NumType_& z() {
        static_assert(Size_ > 2, "Must contain a minimum of 3 elements for z.");
        return elements[2];
    }
};
```

This relies on the rules of [implicit template instantiation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst), which state that:

- When a class template is implicitly instantiated, [the declarations of its member functions are also implicitly instantiated... but the *definitions* aren't](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#2).
- If a function template isn't explicitly instantiated, and isn't explicitly specialised, [it will be implicitly specialised when it needs to be](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#4).

Combined, these two rules mean that the functions will always be visible for any `Vector`, but they'll break the moment you call them if `Size_` isn't large enough.

```
Vector<1, int> v1i;

v1i.x() = 3; // Instantiates Vector<1, int>::x().  1 > 0, so we're good.
v1i.y() = 6; // Instantiates Vector<1, int>::y().  !(1 > 1), so static_assert emits an error.
v1i.z() = 9; // Instantiates Vector<1, int>::y().  !(1 > 2), so static_assert emits an error.
```

[This will function as desired](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b26e85a5ea04f7e)... provided nobody thinks to stat explicitly instantiate things to speed up compilation!

<sup>Note that I changed the underscores in your template parameters' names from prefix to postfix, to comply with language rules regarding underscores followed by capitals.</sup>